# FileReader seems like its not working

Tags: java, filereader

I have a simple problem that I cant see, hopefully another set of eyes can help me out. Everything works perfectly except what I think is the filereader. Im supposed to get the users input putting it to a file, reading that file and doing the correct actions. But for some reason its only doing it to the last input the user entered and doing it the amount of times the user wanted to run the program.

so for example user puts in 3 times he wants to run the prompt, he enters 344.34, 5533.23, 34.55, it saves it to the file correctly but the output file has

```
Thirty-four dollars and 55 cents
Thirty-four dollars and 55 cents
Thirty-four dollars and 55 cents
```

I cant figure out why its doing this. Thanks

```
   public class Driver 
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {    
    // reads from keyboard
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    //writes to file
    FileWriter fw =new FileWriter("input.txt");  
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    double input; //variable to get users input

    System.out.println("How many times do you want to convert? ");
    int amount = kb.nextInt();
    //loop to go through users inputs and save to file
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter currency to change to words: ");  
        while(!kb.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a correct currency: ");
            kb.next();
        }

        input = kb.nextDouble();
        bw.write(String.valueOf(input));
        bw.newLine();
        amount--;

    }while(amount > 0 );
    bw.close();

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Karmen\\workspace\\currencytoword\\input.txt"));
    FileWriter fw2 =new FileWriter("output.txt");  
    BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);

    double input2;

    // loop to go through the file read and get convert the curreny to words and save in a output file.
    while(read.hasNext())
    {
        input2 = read.nextDouble();
        int dollar = (int) input2;
        int cents = (int)Math.round((input2 - dollar) * 100);
        String word = numToWord(dollar);
        if(word == "null")
        {
            bw2.write("Number too large");
        }
        else
            bw2.write(input + ": " + word + " dollars and " + cents + " cents");
            bw2.newLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Program is done");
    bw2.close();
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  The only bug I can find is that when you write your output file you are prepending `input` instead of `input2` to each line.  When I run your program the 'from' value is wrong, but the converted values are all correct.  Are you sure that the code you are running is what you've posted here?  Try recompiling and running it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found your problem. It's here:

```
else
        bw2.write(input + ": " + word + " dollars and " + cents + " cents");
        bw2.newLine();
```

You're writing `input` when you really should be writing `input2`.
So correct code is:

```
else
        bw2.write(input2 + ": " + word + " dollars and " + cents + " cents");
        bw2.newLine();
```

This illustrates why you really should use variables names that are more descriptive and not self-similar; it helps prevent silly little errors. (For example, here, `userInput` and `fileInput` would be much better variable names than `input` and `input2`)

Comment: Descriptive variable names also makes debugging easier as you can seek the variable you desire in the debugger more easily.

Comment: This is the same problem @azurefrog mentioned. I only get the item before the colon repeated, the actual conversion prints correctly.